Is this mold on ceiling dry wall near kitchen?
A few weeks back, we saw square shaped crack in our drywall ceiling and small black spots forming near it.This is in our kitchen and above kitchen is our master bath. We cut open the dry wall few days ago and didn't see any water leak. Could this be mold from humidity and cooking in the kitchen ?
The snippet inside the red circle is what showed up on our drywall ceiling. And we used a tool to detect what kind of material is behind the dry wall - and it showed us a metal. So we did not cut drywall over it instead we cut the drywall surrounding it. And we saw that there is a supporting metal piece inside.
2 questions:

What could be the reason for the square shape etching on our drywall ceiling underneath the metal support ?
What are the black spots on the drywall ? Could that be mold ?




theres not enough information here to help answer your question. It just looks like you drew a few lines on a wall and cut a hole out of drywall.

Updated the description. Please check @wahwahwah

The "square shape etching" is most likely an old junction box outlet. So be careful if youre futzing-around. And, as far as I can see, the "black specks" on the board are normal for pine.

So, it's probably empty, but that "square spaced etching" might have live wires behind it, be careful.

The square-shaped cracking looks to me like the drywall has been pushed up against the metal joist hanger above it, stressing it to the point it has cracked. This doesn't look like surface mold to me, just normal kitchen dirt/grease. Does a slightly damp rag smear or clean it off? We would need more information (i.e., photos) of the joist space to see if there is any evidence of moisture or mold, but from the one picture I don't see any.

@spuck - exactly the point - there is no live wires. It is metal joist hanger pushing close to drywall. We had a upstairs master bathroom repair few months ago and as part of that there was lot of breaking the tiles on the floor, fixing them etc. Not sure if this is side effect of such repair. What else could be causing such metal joist pushing close to drywall ? It is 24 year old home. Should we be concerned about this ? I was thinking of bringing a structural engineer to inspect ? What are your thoughts ? Am I getting overly worried ?

@user2548103, I can't comment on what level of inspection would put your mind at ease, but drywall is never structural and I would not worry about it. As to what caused the metal joist hanger to be pushed close to the drywall: it was installed that way 24 years ago. Breaking up tiles/pounding the floor above certainly could have caused a cosmetic crack to appear, as could have any stresses from below pushing up on the drywall... installing new cabinets, or even just normal settling of the home.

First pic looks just like dust to me.

@spuck - it could also be a bad patch job, and nothing to worry about. (including all you said previously, in comments... you're probably correct.) I'd just discourage digging around without testing for loose wires. And, thats where the OP needs to know what their doing (to test) or hire someone. I've had people get shocked when they though everything was dead next to boxes like this. Better to be safe

I would have just made sure the power was off and ripped the thing out of the wall. If there's no moister, and the electric is good, just replace or patch. @spuck is right... if your home has structural integrity issues supported by drywall, you've got bigger issues that what you just showed in the photos
